# Analysing a graph returned from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have a function `My(n)` that takes input as `n` and returns a graph. How do I use the graph returned from the function and find the number of edges for different n values ?

Function:

```
def My(n):
    l= nx.Graph
    ....
    .... 
    ... #Ommitted definitions as its too long
    return nx.draw(l, with_labels = True)
```

I tried defining my function as a variable:
for example for `n = 5` and my function `My(n)` which returns a graph satisfying some properties.

```
B = My(5) 
print(B.number_of_nodes())
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'number_of_nodes'

I guess because `B` is a function and not a graph? How do I analyse the graph my function produces?

Comment: Evidently your function `My` does not return a graph. It returns `None`.

Comment: It returns a graph when I run it.

Comment: The error message says it returns `None`, even if you think otherwise. From what you've posted, `My` returns the return value of `nx.draw`. Did you check what `nx.draw` is supposed to return?

Comment: you return "nx.draw(l, with_labels = True)" . now that is a function, and functions translate to a single value. In this case, a None apparently. So, even though i presume nx.draw is responsible for drawing the graph, or taking an action that gets you to view a graph, it itself is still not a graph. It is a function with probably no return value, or None.

Comment: You're right. I get a none value. So how do I convert the value into a 'graph' that I can analyse? Can I say My(n) = nx.Graph()

Comment: What's the purpose of `My(n)`? Where are you even using `n`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would suggest something like this

```
def buildGraph(n):
    g = nx.Graph()
    # add to g
    return g

g = buildGraph(5)
nx.draw(g, with_labels = True)
```

Basically, the draw function isn't returning the Graph, it's displaying a window, and returning nothing